# cout not printing to terminal screen C++

Tags: c++

I'm running a .cpp file and trying to print out to the screen for debugging purposes, however my message does not appear. I'm running my program from the Linux  Terminal using the following command:

```
g++ -m32 -static genConfig.cpp -o genConfig
```

All that my .cpp file should do at this point is cout to the terminal as show below. However the output doesn't appear.

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    cout<<"HEYYYA";

}
```

Comment: Do you actually run it? i.e., `./genConfig`? `g++` only compiles(doesn't run the binary).

Comment: command you provided is not intended to run your application, it only compiles executable, to run it you need to `./genConfig`

Comment: @ODYN Not necessary in C++.

Comment: You should add `#include <iostream>` to your application too.

Comment: You should flush the output buffer by appending '\n' to the stream, using `std::endl` or calling `std::cout.flush()`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Open streams are flushed automatically when the program exits.

Comment: Thanks guys, I\`m new to this so I didn`t know the difference between compiling and running, could you remove the downvotes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `g++ -m32 -static genConfig.cpp -o genConfig` does not *run* the application, it *compiles* (and *links*) it. In order to run the generated binary, you need to execute `./genConfig`.

Also, you need `#include <iostream>` and actually `#include <string>` is not needed (at least not for this specific portion of code).

Comment: Depending on your shell/prompt, you still might not see anything. The fix is to terminate your output lines properly: `cout<<"HEYYYA\n";`

Comment: Thanks, I`m new to this so I didn`t know the difference between compiling and running :)

Comment: Also, just to be clear, compiling and linking is g++ parsing my code and understanding what it says, and running is the file executing, is that correct?

Comment: @Ken You're welcome. Compilation is the process of converting source code to machine code, i.e. code that the computer can actually execute. In the case of g++, the _compiler_ converts the source code into assembly code, which the _assembler_ turns into "object code", which in turn the _linker_ "links" into an executable file. You may benefit from reading about `compiling`, `linking` and `interpreting` regarding programming languages.